# Creating dual slider for sencha touch app

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-applications, sencha-touch

I am trying to create a dual slider in my sencha touch mobile app and I don't find a way to create it. Unfortunately my application is in an older version of sencha touch which is 1.1.1 . I know that we can create multiple thumbs for a slider. But I am unable to create thumbs and pass it to my slider. Could you please provide me a solution for this ? If creating multiple thumbs is the solution, then could anyone please provide a sample of creating "Ext.form.Slider.Thumb" and passing it to slider.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty easy. In the latest Sencha Touch, you can do it(As you know). Try this:

```
    {
        xtype: 'sliderfield',
        label: 'Price Range',
        value: [50,70],
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100
    }
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anandkgupta/sZ96p/7/).

Let me know if it helps.

**------------------------------------- **EDIT **------------------------------------------**

Add this [file](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/source/Slider2.html#Ext-field-Slider) in your project, and give it a try. This is `Slider.js` of Sencha framework which is responsible for sliderfield. This may solve your problem.